# Problems with Rave Reports 7.7BE scripts

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, rave-reports

I have an application that uses Rave Reports.

After upgrading from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2010 some scripts stopped working and gives an 
**Access violation message**

I have a script that looks like this:

**OnGetText:**

```
 IF  (ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsInteger = 1)  THEN
    Value := 'TEST ' + ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsString ; 
ELSE
     Value := 'TEST ';  
 END IF;
```

This script works in Rave 6.5BE(D2006) but not Rave 7.7BE (D2010)

**Note:**

**Command** :    Value := 'TEST ' + ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsString ;

works without the  If and EndIf statements.

**Command** :   Value := 'TEST ';

works without the  If and EndIf statements.

**Command** :    if (ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsInteger = 1)  THEN

Gives the Access violation message

**Command** :    if (ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsString = ‘1’)  THEN

Gives the Access violation message

**I just don’t see where I am going wrong…**

please help.

Comment: @Charles: "gives an Access violation message" doesn't tell anyone anything. What is the *exact* error message (including addresses) of the AV? You need to provide useful information if you want to receive useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Method AsInteger causes application's AV in rave 7.7. (AsString works fine)

replace it with: `if (ddvDetailTaxidEventType.AsString = '1') then`

https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=31157&tstart=0

Comment: Rave Reports 7.7BE   is full of bugs – It has made migrating software from Delphi 2006 to Delphi 2010 a nightmare.
Rave Reports 8.0BE has just as many bugs.